# Align text with pcr font

Tags: fonts, horizontal-alignment

When I change the font from default to pcr (by following this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/25251#25251)) it seems that my text loses its alignment (justified) and the text covers the margin.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{geometry, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}  

\section{Properly aligned (justified) with default font}  
\lipsum[1] 

\section{I change font to pcr and the text is not properly aligned}  
\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont  
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you trying to typeset a document entirely in Courier? If not, can you please show a “real world” application?

Comment: @egreg No, I just want to insert some comments in the Courier font (I choosed the pcr, because it is very distinguishable to the default font that I use elsewhere). But then, without the alignment, my comments seem to sloppy. You mean to show proper text and not the \lipsum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just for comments, I'd use ragged right. Anyway, here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{jcomment}
 {\par\addvspace{\medskipamount}%
  \normalfont\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont
  \ifnum\hyphenchar\font=`\- \else\hyphenchar\font`\-\fi
  \spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus .5\fontdimen2\font minus .2\fontdimen2\font
  \ignorespaces}
 {\par\addvspace\medskipamount}


\begin{document}

\section{Properly aligned (justified) with default font}
\lipsum[2]

\section{I change font to pcr and the text is not properly aligned}

\begin{jcomment}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{jcomment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works too. I will indeed go with \raggedright, I just did not think about it. Its the simplest for my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based in that you  only want distinguishable comments, my suggestion  is not use the courier font for this, but  a "typewriter" but proportional font as *Latin Modern Mono Proportional* or *Latin Modern Mono Z*:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}  
%\renewcommand*\ttdefault{lmvtt} % for Latin Modern Mono Proportional
\usepackage[scaled=1.05,proportional,lightcondensed]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}  
\section{Justified with standard font}  
\lipsum[1] 
\section{May be better not change to \texttt{pcr}}  
\ttfamily
\lipsum*[1]
\end{document}
```

Of course, use `{\ttfamily ...}` or `\texttt{...}` to limit the scope of the typerwriter font.

Answer (score 1):

This is my result:
[image]

I just changed the interword space settings. As reported in http://texblog.net/latex-archive/plaintex/full-justification-with-typewriter-font/

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{geometry, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\usepackage{everysel}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
\EverySelectfont{
\fontdimen2\font=0.3em
\fontdimen3\font=0.2em
\fontdimen4\font=0.1em
\fontdimen7\font=0.1em
\hyphenchar\font=`\-
}

\begin{document}  

\section{Justified with standard font}  
\lipsum[1] 

\section{I change font to ``pcr'' and this is not justified}  
\fontfamily{pcr}\selectfont  
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\EverySelectfont` like that is really the last thing to do. Anyway, the text appears justified to me.

Comment: Thank you (+1), this works. I am using the pcr font only in a small part of my article (to insert comments that I want to be distinguishable). Will the command \EverySelectfont, as @egreg comments, affect also the rest of the document? Should I avoid it. Thank you!

Comment: @JimmyR.  Just remove `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}`. May be the result will look nicer using also the `microtype` package.